# Exibir PoPup com página do facebook para o usuários, mostrar uma vez a cada 7 dias

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/www.maroclub.net/" data-width="150" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Esse é o código do facebook, um botão para curti página, Quero que exiba após 10 segundos que o usuário abrir a página. Se souberem alguma função que verifica se ele já curtiu  a página por favor adicionem, por que nesse caso só exibiria se o usuário não curtiu ainda o que seria melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função que verifica se ele já curtiu eu desconheço!

**Biblioteca**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML Modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
                <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

                <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/www.maroclub.net/" data-width="150" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT** - comentários no código

```
//verifica se o cookie não existe ou se já está expirado 
if (document.cookie.indexOf("visita=") < 0) {  
    //abre o modal em 10 segundos
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal();
    }, 10000);
   //grava cookie
   var date = new Date();
   //expira em 7 dias
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000));
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

   document.cookie = "visita=realizada"+expires+"; path=/";

}
```